# Cannot install pyOTDR

Tags: python, pip

I need to install pyOTDR but some issues are preventing me to do so.
As suggested in the webpage, I tried

```
pip install pyOTDR
```

but I get

> Command errored out with exit status 1

This is the whole console log:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\campione\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\campione\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fiabozry\\lazyxml\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\campione\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fiabozry\\lazyxml\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\campione\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_nv05fei'
         cwd: C:\Users\campione\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fiabozry\lazyxml\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\campione\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fiabozry\lazyxml\setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        import lazyxml
      File "C:\Users\campione\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fiabozry\lazyxml\lazyxml\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
        from . import builder
      File "C:\Users\campione\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fiabozry\lazyxml\lazyxml\builder.py", line 7, in <module>
        import utils
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm completely new to Python so bear with me, but I think it can maybe be related to "utils" module missing, as you can read at the end.

I don't understand why I could install other python packages in the same way but not this one unfortunately.

Comment: The page says, use "pip install pyotdr" (lower case) for the normal install. I'd try that first. Also, you're on Windows, so you should check if the project works on windows - some libraries don't. This one seems pretty new, so if you can't get it to install, file an issue on github with the project itself.

Comment: For fun I tried installing it on Win10, 64bit, using Python 3.7 and the import of lazyxml breaks. The error points to a cp1252 codepage error, this usually is a windows problem. So verify that this should run on windows, if not, run it on Linux. As the project runs on both Python3 and Python2, it may be worth trying with Python2...

Comment: Also, you should always run `python -m pip install <package_name>` instead. This is recommended by the python docs and tells you the python version you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Python 3 and installing Python 2 worked for some reason.